# How can I compare the content of two (or more) MSI files?

Tags: installation, msi, windows-installer

How can I do a "**content compare**" of two (or more) **MSI files** and see what is actually different inside the files - instead of doing a **useless binary compare**? (which obviously only tells me if I am dealing with copies of the same file or not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### MSI Files

An MSI file contains **a primitive MS SQL database** embedded in a **COM-structured storage file** (a file system in a file with storage streams of various types - the old MS Office COM/OLE format).

You can **extract** files from an MSI, or you can actually **decompile** the whole MSI with all its streams. Each approach is described briefly below.

With decompilation (almost) full transparency is possible, with the exception of compiled custom actions (generally written in C/C++). Managed, compiled code (C#) may actually be (theoretically) decompiled.

In order to determine (roughly) what a black-box custom action actually does, you can capture an MSI install using [a repackaging tool](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/tt_corp.htm) - which scans the system before and after installation listing any changes - you see what has happened, but not how it has happened. Very few people have the need for this level of scrutiny.

### File Compare Only

This is old news, but if all you are concerned with is **comparing the files embedded in the MSI / setup.exe**, you can use an **[administrative installation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367541(v=vs.85).aspx)** to extract the files embedded in the MSI / setup.exe and then use any file compare tool to compare the files extracted for each version:

- `setup.exe /a`
- `msiexec.exe /a "MySetup.msi"`

If the MSI lacks proper GUI to allow you to specify an output folder interactively, you can try to specify it via the command line:

- `msiexec.exe /a "MySetup.msi" TARGETDIR="C:\MyOutputFolder`

Setup.exe files containing embedded MSI files may be of various types, some pointers:

- [Some Installshield-specific information on setup.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681252/programmatically-extract-contents-of-installshield-setup-exe/8694205#8694205)
- [Handling other setup.exe types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221983/how-can-i-use-powershell-to-run-through-an-installer/46224987#46224987)

Essentially an administrative installation **extracts the setup's files** from the embedded CAB files in the MSI itself (CABS can also be external) and outputs them in a **neat folder structure** roughly reflecting their intended target destinations upon install. [Several forms of compression may be used in an MSI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6313772/129130) - all handled by the administrative installation. [Please do not unzip MSI files](https://superuser.com/questions/307678/how-do-i-extract-files-from-an-msi-package/788227#788227)!

Finally the `Media table` is adjusted to use the now extracted source files instead of the internal CAB files - and the internal CAB files are deleted potentially making the output MSI much smaller than the original. Crucially any **digital signatures are removed**.

It used to be that MSI files were cached in `%SystemRoot%\Installer` stripped of their CAB files (making them small), but they are now cached full-size, potentially dramatically increasing storage requirements. Using administrative installs is a way to reduce this caching size (with the penalty of the removed digital signatures). More on this here: [Why does MSI require the original .msi file to proceed with an uninstall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208530/why-does-msi-require-the-original-msi-file-to-proceed-with-an-uninstall/1189524#1189524)

Further details on administrative installations here:

- [What is the purpose of administrative installation initiated using msiexec /a?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564619/what-is-the-purpose-of-administrative-installation-initiated-using-msiexec-a/5751980#5751980)
- [Extract MSI from EXE - performing an admin install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547809/extract-msi-from-exe/24987512#24987512)

---

### "MSI Content Compare"

If you want to determine in more detail what is different between two MSI files (for example version 1 and 2 of a package), you can get a little more involved using a proper **MSI file viewer** or **MSI decompiler**.

I wrote a blurb on [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) on **how to compare MSI files**. It has been suggested to me to add a link here on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) to this content. Maybe it is helpful for system administrators.

I don't want to have a dual-source problem, so I will just link to the stackoverflow-version (hope that is OK practice): [**How can I compare the content of two (or more) MSI files?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482545/how-can-i-compare-the-content-of-two-or-more-msi-files) This answer lists several tools (both free and commercial) that can help you get a "real comparison" done.

***The advanced MSI decompilation abilities of `dark.exe` from the WiX toolkit may be of particular interest***. In addition to MSI file decompilation, the linked content also describes how to decompress `setup.exe` files created with the [WiX toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864) (a bootstrapper feature that can install several MSI files and embedded EXE files in sequence). The decompressed content can in turn be dissembled by the same `dark.exe` file (provided they are MSI files).

Let me also throw in a link on [how to handle setup.exe files made with other deployment tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221983/how-can-i-use-powershell-to-run-through-an-installer/46224987#46224987).